# maven-glassfish-plugin can't get maven-metadata.xml

Tags: java, maven, glassfish

I have used this plugin for one year.But several days ago,it stopped when tried to get some metadata.xml files from ocean.net.au.

Downloading: http://maven.ocean.net.au/release/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://maven.ocean.net.au/snapshot/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://maven.ocean.net.au/external/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml

Why this plugin needs to get these metadata.xml files every time?
It seems the ocean.net.au site is down,did you run into the same problem?I am in China,we have GFW.
Can I let this plugin don't download metadata.xml files each time?

Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you using Maven Central ? in combination with a repository manager ? Usually these metadata files will be called only once a day, depending your configuration (settings.xml http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories)

Comment: Yes,I don't want to use maven.ocean.net,but how to do?

Comment: Are you using a downloaded version of version or an internal company version? You should check the settings.xml as mentioned earlier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use the command line to do this. It's easy.

Start `domain1` in debug mode:

```
asadmin start-domain --debug=true domain1
```

Deploy an application:

```
mvn clean install
asadmin --host=localhost --port=4848 --passwordfile=$GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish_password --echo=true --interactive=false deploy --force=true --name=jsf2 --contextroot=kaimei ./target/kaimei.war
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I set the domain to resolve to a running apache. So I had not to wait for the timeout. I used my local domain but I do have by default an apache running. So you might need to change it to an IP of an always up service (for example, google company website, ..)

On (most) linux (and mac?) it's in

> /etc/hosts (need to be root).

On windows

> Windows 95/98/Me:  c:\windows\hosts 
>   Windows NT/2000/XP Pro:  c:\winnt\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
>   Windows XP Home: c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
>   Windows Vista: c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

You execute a ping for finding the ip (ex: google')

```
lucs@worf:~$ ping www.google.com
PING www.l.google.com (173.194.65.147) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

You can add flowing line in your host-file (ex: google').

```
173.194.65.147    maven.ocean.net.au
```